# Duda acerca del funcionamiento de font-size al momento de darle valor de 100% en body

Tags: html5, css3

No entiendo muy bien lo que ocurre cuando le asigno font-size: 100% al elemento body, entiendo que toma el tamaño de la fuente en porcentaje de su padre, lo que significa que todo el texto dentro de body tiene ese tamaño, si tenemos dos etiquetas de encabezado h estas segun lo que entiendo deberian tener el tamaño de fuente que se le asigno a body, pero los h tienen su propio tamaño y se supone que deberian tener el tamaño de fuente que se le dio a body porque son texto dentro de body como tal y a body se le asigno en porcentaje el tamaño de fuente de su padre que seria el elemento html.

Esto es porque los elementos h no son texto propio de body si no que son elementos independientes y esto solo aplica a contenido de texto?

Lei que el inicializar el font-size:100%; ayuda a que el texto de los encabezados se muestren iguales en todos los navegadores, pero no entiendo muy bien exactamente porque hacer eso hace que el texto se vea igual en todos lados.

Agradeceria que me ayudaran a resolver esa duda, yo realmente estoy muy confundido con el tema.

¿El tamaño por defecto de html siempre sin importar el navegador seria 16px por ende body tendria eso?

Comment: El navegador aplica reglas por defecto a cada elemento HTML; es por eso que una estructura HTML no se ve exactamente igual en todos los navegadores. Por esta razón, existen los los llamados "reset" css, que son hojas estilos que "resetean" los elementos HTML para que sean homogéneos en todos los navegadores.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

no he entendido muy bien la pregunta pero creo que me puedo hacer una idea de como ayudarte.

En html los `h1` tienen unos estilos por defecto al tener ese tag. Los estilos css que pertenezcan a un hijo del `body` o un hijo de cualquier elemento html siempre se van a sobrescribir sobre los del padre, razón por la cual los estilos del `h1` se te están manteniendo aunque el `body` tenga otro valor para el `font-size`.

Imaginemos que tienes un `font-size: 14px` en el body `font-size: 18px` en el `h1`. El `font-size` que se mantendrá será el `18px`.

Si añades `font-size: 100%` en el css del elemento `h1` en específico éste sobreescribirá a los estilos que tiene el `h1` por defecto y buscará el `font-size` del padre o del `body` (según cual sea).

Espero haberte ayudado. Si te queda alguna duda, añade un comentario a esta respuesta y así podremos especificar un poco más para que te pueda entender mejor.

Un saludo :)